# What is the easier way to split an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I have one problem at that point when I tried to split an array into some subarrays.

To be more exactly I have an array, let's say `int a[10]={1,3,2,7,8,12,5,7,68,10}` and I'm running my program on X process (in this moment I'm using 8 but could be more or less).

And I want to sent to each process on part of this array, for example for my array in this moment each process will receive something like `process0 = {1, 3}`, `process2 = {2, 7}` and so on.. until `process7 = 68, 10`.

After I've send each subarray I will do some operations on each subarray and after I want to merge all my subarrays into one back.

I've search on google a lot and I saw some example using `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` **or** `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` and I've tried some methods but everything I've tried... was without success and I receive errors or
null pointer...

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 32 
int A[N]; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size;
    int rank;
    const int ROOT = 0; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int count = N / (size - 1);

    int *localArray = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10;
        }

        for (int dest = 1; dest < size; ++dest) {
            MPI_Send(&A[(dest - 1) * count], count, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("P0 sent a %d elements to P%d.\n", count, dest);
        }

        for (int source = 1; source < size; source++) {
            MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            //--------------------------------MERGE THE ALL RESULTS INTO A SORTED ARRAY-------------------------------------
            printf("Received results from task %d\n", source);
        }
    }
    else {
        MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        //---------------SORT THE localArray-------------------
        MPI_Send(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

What ever I've tried I can't get results where I've put the comment, what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While dreamcrash already suggested you could clean up your code using scatter & gather, I would put more emphasis on this. **Use the built-in collective operations wherever possible. Do not try to rebuild them on your own.** Not only is the code cleaner and easier to understand, it will also be significantly faster and allow all sorts of optimizations by the MPI implementation. Your example (assuming `N` is divisible by `size`) becomes:

```
if (rank == ROOT) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

MPI_Scatter(A, count, MPI_INT, localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//---------------SORT THE localArray-------------------
MPI_Gather(localArray, count, MPI_INT, A, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Finalize();
```

Note that the `ROOT` rank correctly participates in the computation and does send data to itself using scatter / gather without any additional code path.

Now since your example explicitly uses `N=10`, which is not divisible by `size=8`, here is a version that works correctly. The idea is to distribute the `remainder` of the integer division evenly across the first `remainder` ranks (each gets one additional element to work on). You have to do that irregardless of using send/recv or scatter/gather. With scatter/gather you use the `MPI_Scatterv` / `MPI_Gatherv` variants, which take an array of `sendcounts` (how much elements does each rank get) and `displacements` (offset of each local part within the global one):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 32 
int A[N]; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size;
    int rank;
    const int ROOT = 0; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // compute the work distribution
    int remainder = N % size;
    int local_counts[size], offsets[size];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        local_counts[i] = N / size;
        if (remainder > 0) {
            local_counts[i] += 1;
            remainder--;
        }
        offsets[i] = sum;
        sum += local_counts[i];
    }

    int localArray[local_counts[rank]];

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(A, local_counts, offsets, MPI_INT, localArray, local_counts[rank], MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //---------------SORT THE localArray-------------------

    MPI_Gatherv(localArray, local_counts[rank], MPI_INT, A, local_counts, offsets, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 32 
int A[N];  // this should be global

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size;
    int rank;
    const int VERY_LARGE_INT = 999999;
    const int ROOT = 0; 
    int tag = 1234;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int count = N / size ;

    int *localArray = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    int localMin;  // minimum computed on rank i
    int globalMin; // will only be valid on rank == ROOT

    if (rank == ROOT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
        // master local copy
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            localArray[i] = A[i];

        for (int dest = 1; dest < size; ++dest) {
            MPI_Send(&A[dest* count], count, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("P0 sent a %d elements to P%d.\n", count, dest);
        }
        localMin = VERY_LARGE_INT;

    for (int source = 1; source < size; source++) 
    {
        MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        //--------------------------------I CANT GET RESULT HERE-------------------------------------
        printf("Received results from task %d\n", source);
    }

    }
    else 
    {
        MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

       //.. do something
       MPI_Send(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Some mistakes:

- Array `A` is global, therefore all processes will have it, you most
  likely want to only allocate it for the master process;
- I changed `N / (size - 1)` to `N / size`, however be aware that this
  only works when N %% size == 0, thus you might want to deal with opposed 
  scenario.
- Since the master will have a sub-copy of the global array, I am performing this local copy from A to local array before sending the data to the slaves :

  ```
  // master local copy
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      localArray[i] = A[i];
  ```
- You have a small mistake on the merging part, the master and the slaves are using different tags, that was causing a deadlock. That is why I also changed this:

  `MPI_Send(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

  to

  `MPI_Send(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

  Both have now the same tag (2);
- You could implement this code with scatter and gather and it would be a lot cleaner see [here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) some examples.

Another mirror issue is if you are using C language instead of  `int *localArray = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));` you should do `int *localArray = malloc(count * sizeof(int));` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) why.